# Arguments passed to SQL*Plus script override the arguments of script which invoked it

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

file2.sql

```
set serveroutput on
exec dbms_output.put_line('invoke file2.sql');
```

file1.sql

```
exec dbms_output.put_line('&1');
@file2.sql 'col2' 'col1'
exec dbms_output.put_line('&1');
```

I am executing @file1.sql 'col1'.  Please find the output below.

@f1.sql   col1

col1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

invoke file2.sql

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

col2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>

I am expecting to print 'col2' after invoking file2.sql but its gets overriden with the value passed to file2.sql. How to overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the original argument in a new variable:

file1.sql:

```
prompt Argument 1 = &1
define somevar = &1

@file2.sql col2 col1

prompt Original argument 1 = &somevar
```

Output:

```
SQL> @file1.sql col1
Argument 1 = col1
This is file2.sql
Original argument 1 = col1
```

Comment: I will be using &1 value subsequently in file.sql. so, I wish to retain the value in &1 as it is passed while invoking file1.sql. Is there a way to achieve this or a way to restrict overriding values of arguments passed to the invoking file.

Comment: `define 1 = &somevar` after calling file2.sql? But surely copying the numbered positional values to explicitly named variables that you can control seems like a more robust approach. Why stick to `&1` when you can use `&customer_id`?

Comment: Ya got it. Thanks!